# Using a stock photo for 3d modeling, and redistributing

Tags: copyright

I wanted to take a photo from https://www.istockphoto.com/ and use it as a base to create a 3d model.

The photo would be an essential feature of the model, without the photo the model could not exist.

Would redistributing the model for free be possible following the license provided by the website? I would be happy to consider both the standard and extended license if any of those would allow me to execute and redistribute my work giving due credits to the author.

Comment: What does the specific license text say for the standard and extended licenses on that image?

Comment: This is the license agreement for all media on istockphoto https://www.istockphoto.com/legal/license-agreement

Comment: I gave it a look but didn't find anything that would correspond to what I want to do

Comment: Do you intend to purchase a license or just use the watermarked preview?

Comment: Did you ask istockphoto? They have a Contact Us link on their site.

Comment: I haven't asked yet. I do intend to purchase if it is needed for me to share without repercussions.

Comment: @bracco23 Is there a reason you chose to ask random people on the internet rather than the company licensing it?

Comment: If they have a license, then you are allowed to do anything allowed either by the license or by copyright law. Anything else I’d not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, the license allows this though I'm baffled as to why you're asking random people rather than the site licensing it.

The license offers unlimited use, including modification, with some restrictions. This would include making a derivative work from it and distributing that.

The only restriction likely to be an issue is that you cannot falsely claim authorship of the photo. It is likely you would need to attribute it, depending on how much your 3d model uses it.